# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio says that RowVersion is invalid type

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-express

Is there a way when creating a tables through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, to specify a field as [RowVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) rather than Timestamp?

This is what I get when I try to use rowversion as a type of a field:

[image]

I am on Windows 7 64bit, SQL Server 2014 Express, and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17.1

Comment: Have you tried timestamp ?

Comment: @MalvEarp Yeah, I can use timestamp. I just didn't know that rowversion is typealias for timestamp... https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86523/microsoft-recommends-using-rowversion-over-timestamp-but-i-can-not-find-rowve

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't have enough reputation to post a comment. This has been asked before. below is the link

if you are using GUI,then use `TimeStamp' which is how`rowversion` is stored under the hoods

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.x(y ROWVERSION);
```

even the above ddl under the hoods will be stored as `Timestamp`,you can verify the same using below

```
SELECT t.name 
  FROM sys.types AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
  INNER JOIN sys.tables AS st
    ON c.[object_id] = st.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON st.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE st.name = N'x'
    AND s.name = N'dbo'
    AND c.name = N'y';
```

**References:**
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86523/microsoft-recommends-using-rowversion-over-timestamp-but-i-can-not-find-rowve

Comment: Okay, thanks... I guess I should use timestamp then.

Comment: @Whirlwind, yea, until Microsoft gets around to fixing the SSMS table designer UI. One reason I prefer DDL scripts.

Comment: April 2021 and SSMS V18.7.1  still does not support RowVersion, only TimeStamp